# stylesheet new font font-face import error

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

when i add a new font to my website and it not show shows

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'blacker_pro_display-bold';
src: url('https://colabrio.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/webfonts/blacker_pro_display-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://colabrio.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/webfonts/blacker_pro_display-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
.about_us_font{
font-family: 'blacker_pro_display-bold';
```

Comment: Have you checked in your browsers dev tools that the font has loaded?

Comment: no its not loaded why

Comment: Did you see an error message in console?

Answer (score 0):

Its a CORS issue.

The code is correct, but the browser security settings prevent you from fetching the font file from another domain. The owners of that server have set it so that browesers should not fetch the assets without permission. Find a another source for the font files, host them yourself or fix the CORS headers in the server.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS